# Puppet warping a polygon in Illustrator with internal line-art

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, tools

I am **attempting to warp a leaf symbol** that I made, but the individual elements aren't maintaining their relative positions.
[image: original leaf symbol]

I select, then **add three warp pins** (have tried more, and adding at the intersections):
[image: Leaf symbol with pins added]

I **warp the leaf**:
[image: Warped leaf with mesh visible]

**This is what I get** no matter what I try:
[image: Final resultant warped leaf]

I feel like there's **something fundamental I'm missing, or just misunderstanding** about the puppet warp tool, but I can't figure it out. I've tried:

1. **Grouping the elements differently** (lines grouped together, or nested). Although **perhaps I am not grouping them "properly"**, as I know Illustrator can be picky about how things are grouped (Pathfinder, etc).
2. **Ungrouping all of the elements** in the symbol, so there is only one group (the symbol container itself).
3. **Joining the paths** (although, this creates a contiguous line, which adds more than the art should have).
4. Doing the same thing to the **polygon/line *not* as a symbol**.

Normally I'm pretty good with Illustrator's tools, but the **Puppet Warp has always perplexed me** due to idiosyncrasies like this.

Comment: Make sure the polygon line has a point at eeach intersection

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to group. Select all the inner paths (i.e. the veins of the leaf), then do *Object > Expand*, then open the Pathfinder and do Unite, then select all parts of the leaf, then apply the Puppet Warp and it will work. After this has been done you will find that a group has been applied automatically to all the selected elements in the Puppet Warp.

[image]